# PERFORMANCE Calling multiple times a posgres db to get filtered queries vs querying all objects and filtering in my django view

Tags: django, postgresql, performance, django-models, query-optimization

I'm working in a Django project and it has a postgreSQL db.

I'm calling multiple times the model to filter the results:

```
latest = Product.objects.all().order_by('-update_date')[:4]
best_rate = Product.objects.all().order_by('rating')[:2]
expensive = Product.objects.all().order_by('-price')[:3]
```

But I wonder if it's better for performance and resources consumption to just do 1 query and get all the objects from the database and do the filtering inside my Django view.

```
all = Product.objects.all()
# Do some filtering here iterating over variable all
```

Which of these do you think would be the best approximation? Or do you have a better option?

Comment: There are too many variables to bother guessing about.  If you want to know which is faster, time them and see.

Answer (score 0):

The second way you suggested will be better, you can do this way i guess:

```
products_all = Products.objects.all()
latest = products_all.order_by('-update_date')[:4]
best_rate = products_all.order_by('rating')[:2]
expensive = products_all.order_by('-price')[:3]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you explain why would it be better to use the second option? Are you taking in consideration that I only need 9 objects from the table and that if I use the second option in a table that has millions of objects I'll get the millions of objects instead of just the 9 objects I need?

Answer (score 0):

The point of database tech is to allow your program to work with very large datasets. Your requirement is to retrieve the newest / best / cheapest items from your list of products.

Should you do this with one query operation or three? That depends on how many products you will have in your list when you're running at scale. If you know you will never have more than, say, 100 products, retrieve the data with one query and filter in your Django program. But if you will eventually have thousands of products, use three separate filters.

You don't want your application to take more and more RAM as it scales up.